# Password policies for Google Cloud Platform

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, pci-dss, google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to set password policies for accounts accessing a project on Google Compute Platform?  Specifically, I need to meet the PCI-DSS requirements, which include things that pam would normally handle on ubuntu.  These include expiring passwords every few months, minimum password strength, and preventing re-use of passwords.

For clarity, I'm asking about the developers and admins that have access to the machines, not an application running on the cloud instances.

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Platform does not rely on passwords for authentication (by default) at all and does not manage them for your project.

Feel free to implement your own policies using PAM like in any other environment. You can expect that Cloud Platform management layer will not interfere with them.

Comment: Let me rephrase (I can edit above if I can make it clear) ... Is there a turn-key solution provided with the flexibility to configure password rules for the credentialed accounts?  The docs point to SSH keys are handled and how to work with LDAP, but a solution directly applied to the credentialed accounts would be best.  There's a third-party plug-in for 2-factor auth, which seems a bit big to enforce rules like "passwords should be 8 characters".

Comment: @jimm101 looks like you are looking for full blown Identity and Account Management solution, which is not a part of Google Cloud Platform (yet), unfortunately.